# How create hierarchy using xslt

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSL and am seeking a way to solve some problem. I have xml something like:

```
<Table>
  <Row Id="1">
    <Field1>"P_907"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5912"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  </Row>
  <Row Id="2">
    <Field1>"2.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
  <Row Id="3">
    <Field1>"3.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
  <Row Id="4">
    <Field1>"P_908"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5913"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  </Row>
  <Row Id="5">
    <Field1>"3.11.M2"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Where Row Id=1 and Row Id=4 are headers of invoices and remaining rows are lines of invoices. Every invoice header has its ID in field1 but there is no invoice ID in invoice lines. I know that when there is no field3 in row, it means that row is invoice line. In other case it is invoice header. Every rows before header row belong to previous header row. How create xml with proper invoice hierarchy using xslt?

Output xml could be like:

```
<Invoice>
    <Field1>"P_907"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5912"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"2.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
    <Field1>"P_908"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5913"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.11.M2"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: It's easier to help you getting the desired result if you add the output XML that you want to have to your question.

Comment: could be like: <Invoice>
    <Field1>"P_907"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5912"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"2.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
    <Field1>"P_908"</Field1>
    <Field2>"5913"</Field2>
    <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
    <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.11.M2"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>

Comment: This is a *grouping* question (do a search). Answers will be very different if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One solution is the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="Table">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Row[Field3]">
  <xsl:variable name="invoice-count" select="count(preceding-sibling::Row[Field3]) + 1"/>
   <Invoice>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Row[not(Field3) 
    and not(count(preceding-sibling::Row[Field3]) &gt; $invoice-count)]" mode="copy"/>
    </Invoice>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Row" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Row"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML produces the output

```
<Invoice>
  <Field1>"P_907"</Field1>
  <Field2>"5912"</Field2>
  <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
  <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"2.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.1.1.M5"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
  <Field1>"P_908"</Field1>
  <Field2>"5913"</Field2>
  <Field3>"2013/05/31"</Field3>
  <Field4>"2013/05/31"</Field4>
  <Row>
    <Field1>"3.11.M2"</Field1>
  </Row>
</Invoice>
```

One template matches all `Row` elements that contain a `Field3`:

```
<xsl:template match="Row[Field3]">
```

This template writes an `<Invoice>` node and copies the content of this `Row` by applying templates. Then all following silbing `Row` elements that have no `Field3` and not more preceding sibling `Row` elements with `Field3` than the current `Row` are copied by applying the template `mode="copy"`.
This template copies the content of the `Row` but not the attributes, so the `id` of the `Row` will be removed from the output. 
To avoid writing the `Row` elements twice, the empty template
`<xsl:template match="Row"/>` matches all `Row` nodes that are already handled by applying templates in the template that matches the `Row` elements with `Field3`.

Comment: This does not produce the requested output. Which is hardly surprising, because the condition `not(following-sibling::Row[1][Field3])` has no logical justification (at least not one I can see).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the input, just checked again and noticed what you mean. Will edit or delete in some minutes.

Comment: @pepkas Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so the question will be marked as solved. As I noticed you're maybe new to Stackoverflow and don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using keys as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="Rows" match="Row[not(Field3)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Row[Field3][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[Field3]">
        <Invoice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Rows', generate-id())" mode="followingRows"/>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row" mode="followingRows">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```